# Upload file to WebDAV in UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, stream, webdav

I am trying to implement a write operation on WebDAV storage using [Portable-WebDAV-Library](https://github.com/DecaTec/Portable-WebDAV-Library) but my code

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
var webDavSession = new WebDavSession(@"https://...", credentials);
Uri uri = new Uri("https://.../SubDir/somefile.txt");

try
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
      sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));
      sw.Flush();
      ms.Position = 0;
    }

    await webDavSession.UploadFileAsync(uri, ms);
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

throws the exception "Cannot use the specified Stream as a Windows Runtime IInputStream because this Stream is not readable." I have experimented with IRandomAccessStream and IOutputStream but that yielded other exceptions.

Comment: You can debug it yourself by build WebDAV from your side and check the code around UploadFileAsync, find out which line actually report this error first. As the error info mentioned, it seems like you've passed a stream that is not readable. I do not have the session and uri so I cannot reproduce it from my side. I think you need to debug it yourself first.

Comment: It's the call to `UploadFileAsync` which cannot handle the stream it is given.

Comment: OK. Thanks for sharing. You can close your case now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the `StreamWriter` closed the `MemoryStream` at the end of its using block. So moving the `}` from before to behind of `await webDavSession.UploadFileAsync(uri, ms);` solved the problem:

Before:

```
  ms.Position = 0;
}

await webDavSession.UploadFileAsync(uri, ms);
```

After:

```
  ms.Position = 0;
  await webDavSession.UploadFileAsync(uri, ms);
}
```